# How to make command apm available after installing atom?

Tags: text-editor, package-management

I have installed github's editor atom into `/Application`. I now expected to have the command `apm` at my disposal to be able to install further packages. Yet:

```
$ apm
-bash: apm: command not found
```

How do I get the `apm` command?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By opening atom and going via `Atom > Install Shell Commands` you will get `atom` and `apm` commands.

[image: Screenshot of menu to add commands]

Comment: I've done this and still the command cannot be found in the terminal. Any ideas where it resides so I can modify my bash file?

Comment: @kakubei `$ which apm` gives me `/usr/bin/apm`, so there it should be.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting nothing for `which` or `whereis`, etc.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Try: "sudo apm help" Nothing else worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Atom->Install Shell Commands would install atom and apm commands.

Answer (score 1):

After the Shell Commands installation:

1. MacOSX: Open Terminal and run the "sudo apm install package-name"
2. Windows: Open CMD as administrator and run the "apm install package-name"

Comment: "sudo apm install package-name" worked for me. Nothing else would.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers', if you are using **Atom Beta** and shell commands don't work, pay attention to the names of the installed commands:

[image]

It's not `apm`, it's `apm-beta`!

The last step is to create an alias in ZSH (or similar way in other shell), edit `.zshrc` adding a new line:

```
alias apm=apm-beta
```

Of course, ensure "normal" Atom is not installed to prevent clashes. After this, `apm` should work.